# Tomar el nombre de la ciudad segùn longitud y latitud (Geocodificación inversa)

Tags: javascript, geolocalización

estoy terminando una app la cual se comunica con una pagina web. Desde el celular envió la latitud y longitud del dispositivo a la pagina web y lo guardo en una variable, pero me gustaría poder sacar el nombre de la ciudad en la que se encuentra dicho dispositivo a partir de esa latitud y longitud. 
Estoy trabajando actualmente con openlayers pero no encontrado información a la geocodificacion inversa o ejemplo por lo cual no les puedo dejar código en modo de ejemplo. Desde ya muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

usa esto:

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
 List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(MyLat, MyLong, 1);
 String cityName = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
 String stateName = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1);
 String countryName = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);
```

aqui tienes un ejemplo:
[demo geolocalizacion android](http://www.demoadda.com/demo/android/download-android-background-location-update-service-demo_21)

Comment: Hola Diego ésto es del lado de la pagina web para openlayers? o es de google maps amigo?